Vercel function exclude files
Summary
I am using vercel function to deploy an angular application ssr.
{
  "version": 2,
  "public": true,
  "name": "<project>",
  "rewrites": [
    {
      "source": "/(.*)",
      "destination": "/api"
    }
  ],
  "functions": {
    "api/index.js": {
      "includeFiles": "dist/<project>/**/*",
    }
  }
}

I was working fine until I created some heavy xml files, that make it exceed 250MB. Theses files are not needed inside the functions so I want to exclude it.
Theses files are inside dist/<project>/browser/assets/sitemap
I tried to exclude the files with the excludeFiles
Here are some tries :
 "functions": {
    "api/index.js": {
      "includeFiles": "dist/<project>/**/*",
      "excludeFiles": "dist/<project>/**/*.xml"
    }
  }

  "functions": {
    "api/index.js": {
      "includeFiles": "dist/<project>/**/*",
      "excludeFiles": "dist/<project>/browser/sitemap/**/*"
    }
  }

But each time I get
Error: A Serverless Function has exceeded the unzipped maximum size of 250 MB. : https://vercel.link/serverless-function-size

I am not sur if I can use both includeFiles and excludeFiles property at the same time, if not how can I exclude only one directory from the function ?
Steps to Reproduce

Create an angular app with ssr ng new --ssr
Create the same vercel.json

{
  "version": 2,
  "public": true,
  "name": "<project>",
  "rewrites": [
    {
      "source": "/(.*)",
      "destination": "/api"
    }
  ],
  "functions": {
    "api/index.js": {
      "includeFiles": "dist/<project>/**/*",
      "excludeFiles": "dist/<project>/browser/sitemap/**/*"
    }
  }
}



Create an api/index.js

export default import('../dist/<project>/server/server.mjs').then(
  (module) => module.app(),
);


Add heavy xml file in the src/sitemap folder
Add the sitemap folder in the angular.json

"assets": [
              "src/assets",
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "src/sitemap/",
                "output": "/sitemap/"
              }
            ],

